# Как правильно делегировать js для множества динамических строк?

Tags: javascript, php

У меня есть таблица, в которой создаются динамически поля

У этих полей есть чекбокс, при нажатии на который в базу летит 1 или 0 в зависимости от  состояния чекбокса

Использую делегирование js, но оно работает только на 1 элемент, т.е его сохраняет, а остальные игнорирует

Код js:

```
    let id = $('form').data('id');

    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("click", event => {
        if (event.target.className === "check") {
            document.getElementById(id).submit();
        }
    });
```

Строчка из таблицы

```
<td>
  <form method="post" action="{{ test.id }}/check" id="{{ test.id }}" 
  data-id="{{ test.id }}">
    <input class="check" type="checkbox" name="check"                                           
    {% if test.getChecked == 1 %}checked{% endif %}>
  </form>
</td>
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь что оно не работает?

Comment: @Grundy оно работает, но и в рамках одного родителя всё ок. 
В данной ситуации, описанной выше, работает не корректно

Comment: Возможно класс не совсем тот (например есть ещё классы), рекомендую вместо `className === "check"` использовать `classList.contains('check')`

Comment: `let id = $('form').data('id');` что по твоему возвращает это выражение? Сколько форм у тебя на странице?

Comment: @Grundy оно возвращает id формы, в которой находится чекбокс
1 динамическая строка в таблице - В каждой форма, внутри которой чекбокс

Comment: @EzioMercer увы, но результат тот же

Comment: @Michael, нет, оно возвращает совсем не это. Особенно учитывая что у тебя **несколько** форм

Comment: @Grundy Я понимаю, о чём вы, через data-атрибут я возвращаю id созданной сущности, чтобы по этому же id работать с чекбоксами
Но в итоге, сохраняется значение только первого чекбокса

Comment: @Michael, `id="{{ test.id }}" 
  data-id="{{ test.id }}"` - тут один `id`. `$('form').data('id')` - вернет только первый из набора. если у тебя куча форм - ты всегда тут получить атрибут **только из первой** формы

Comment: @Grundy а как получать не только из первой формы? Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: вообще, странно, почему ты одновременно и jquery используешь и `.addEventListener`?

Comment: @Grundy это 'решение' появилось после кучи неудачных попыток

Answer (score 1):

[Геттер `.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) - возвращает значение связанное **с первым** элементов в выборке.

Выражение `$('form').data('id')` вернет атрибут только для первой формы.

Для решения достаточно использовать [методы `jQuery` для добавления обработчика](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('form').on('click', '.check', function(){
    this.submit();
});
```

Comment: Сам код намного чище моего, и лучше, но увы, работает так же
1 чекбокс из всех строк сохраняется в базу, остальные нет

Comment: @Michael, проверяй что тебе приходит на сервер ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ сейчас все правильно отправляется